# How to go beyond the edge parent element

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

[image]I have a circular  image and a button icon

Lets say image is size of 20x
And button is size of 8x
I want to put the button icon in a way that 80% of its portion stays on the image view and 20% goes beyond it.

My xml code-

```
RelativeLyaout<
 andoird.cardview.widget.Cardview<
   <ImageView/>
 />
 <button_icon>
   layout_alignRight:ImageView 
  </button_icon>
```

ImageViw and button_icon overlaps but not that way I want.

80% portion of the button stays behind the image view that i cant see and the rest 20% of the button that goes beyond the image view is visible

This is for my Android studio app. I things above code is less time consuming.
If you need full code i can provide that too.

Comment: Can u add expected output image with question ?

Comment: Can you add an image for example ? it will be easy to answer in that way !!

Comment: @ADM  i added examole image

Comment: @RAHULPANDEY I added an image reference

Answer (score 0):

you can't exceed parents bounds. but you can introduce one extra layer which will hold both your `View`s and second one may cover part of first one. some basic example with `FrameLayout`

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="#097267">

    <View
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_margin="40dp"
        android:background="#A9C26A">
    
</FrameLayout>
```

also be aware that `elevation` and `translationZ` XML attributes may change order of drawing (first `View` will be drawn on top of second and will cover it). e.g. `Button` have some elevation set by default, also `CardView` ([`setCardElevation(float)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/cardview/widget/CardView#setCardElevation(float))) - additionally (mainly?) this makes some small shadow under these `View`s

Comment: Dint help me.Could you please check out my recently added image references.

Comment: please add XML layout code to your question

Answer (score 0):

Try this code... I have added constraint layout and inside it i have added button overlapping the image.
You can change the size according to your requirements !!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/circleImageView4"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:src="@drawable/blue1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.057"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.166"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/circleImageView4" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```